# What does this represent in java?

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

```
      servicesDto.setPhotospath(values.get("photospath") == null ? null
              :values.get("photospath").toString());
```

What is represented here and why is null used in this manner: '== null ? null'

Note : I am Fresher please give me a such reference and Explain me Bro/Sis/Friends.

Thanking you...!!!

Comment: this is called the [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:)

Comment: @NambiNarayanan I think he's asking about the ternary operator `?`

Comment: Thanks Bro @Kon :) Yes I'm asking about Ternary Operator only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called short form (ternary) if else
your code above is equivalent to the following:

```
if(values.get("photospath") == null){
       servicesDto.setPhotospath(null);
}else{
       servicesDto.setPhotospath(  values.get("photospath").toString())  );
}
```

Comment: Assalamu alaikum @Ahmed Wahbi, Jazakallah for you help bro, Now I got it., :)

Answer (score 1):

in if else notation, this is what it means:

```
if(values.get("photospath") == null ) {
 servicesDto.setPhotospath(null);
}else {
 servicesDto.setPhotospath(values.get("photospath").toString());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for spending some time for me and I got from you what that about code mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

It is a [ternary operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html), and that ternary is equivalent to

```
if (values.get("photospath") == null) {
  servicesDto.setPhotospath(null);
} else {
  servicesDto.setPhotospath(values.get("photospath").toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking at a [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/?%3a):

Properly formatted, one looks like this:

```
 foo.isSomething() ? doThis() : doThat();
```

and translates to: "If the expression before the `?` evaluates to true, execute the statement between the `?` and the `:`, otherwise execute the statement after the `:`."

In other words, you can think of this as shorthand for:

```
 if (foo.isSomething()) {
     doThis();
 } else {
     doThat(); 
 }
```

Note that this is merely a shorthand - there's nothing you can do with a ternary operator that you can't do with if / else statements. That said, you should get familiar with them if you plan to learn programming by exploring professional code (which, incidentally, I recommend strongly), as you'll see it used a lot - not just in Java but in a multitude of languages.

Comment: Yes, Bro I want to learn Programming with professional code. and Thanks alot for this kind info and Keep in touch and Give More answer for my upcoming questions :)

Answer (score 0):

The ternary operator is using one operator to take three operands. It is a conditional operator that provides a shorter syntax for the if...else... statement. The first operand is a boolean expression; if the expression is true then the value of the second operand is returned otherwise the value of the third operand is returned:

boolean expression ? value1 : value2
For example

`boolean isTernary = true;
 String easyToRead = "";
 if (isTernary == true)
 {
     easyToRead = "No";
 }
 else
 {
     easyToRead = "Yes";
 }`
can be written by using the ternary operator:

`boolean isTernary = true;
 String easyToRead = (isTernary == true)?"Yes":"No";`

The if...else... statement which is written in full is easier to read, but sometimes the ternary operator can be a handy syntax shortcut.

Comment: wow It is awesome to know easily @Owen Cao, Thank you Bro. The ternary operator to reduce the code length.